# how to join the members in one class in the order they are clarified?

Tags: scala

I have a case class:

```
case class C(a:String, b:String, c:Int, d:Long, e:String ... )
```

I want to join the members in the class

```
val c = new C("a", "b", 1,  1L, "e" ... )

val joined_str = c.a + c.b + c.c + c.d + c.e ...  // so many members...
```

Is there a function to join the members together easily?
I don't want to write so many member names, because the number of members are so many and the name of members are so long...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer,

```
val c = C("a", "b", 1,  1L, "e")
c.productIterator.mkString(",")
res0: String = a,b,1,1,e
```

Case classes are equipped with a product iterator for iterating over the fields.

Note though that it *looses* type information; for instance,

```
c.productIterator.toArray
res1: Array[Any] = Array(a, b, 1, 1, e)
```

becomes an Array of `Any`.

Comment: Obviously the type is `Any`. In the array, you have `String`, `Int` and `Long`. Also, c.productIterator.toArray.apply(0).isInstanceOf[String] returns true

Answer (score 2):

Scala case classes "implement Product with synthetically generated methods". So, you can you use the provided `productIterator` method to iterate over the members of the case class and then call `mkString` on them.

```
scala> C("a","b",0,1l,"e").productIterator.mkString
res7: String = ab01e
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [productIterator](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Product)

```
  case class C(a: String, b: String, c: Int, d: Long, e: String)
  val c = C("a", "b", 1, 1L, "e")
  c.productIterator.mkString
  //res0: String = ab11e
```